# How to return a value from an asynchronous callback

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I call the method `ReceiveMessage()` from another class. How to return a value `aMessage` from `ReceiveCallback()` to a class where I called `ReceiveMessage()`? `aMessage` is a public field of type string.

```
    public void ReceiveMessage()
    {
      socket.BeginReceive(messageBuffer,0,messageBuffer.Length,SocketFlags.None,ReceiveCallback,null);
    }

    void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            int rec = socket.EndReceive(ar);
            aMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messageBuffer, 0, rec);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("SEND ERROR\n{0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: in short you don't since there is no place to actually catch the return value

Comment: Is the method that calls `ReceiveMessage` an asynchronous method? If not, do you want to wait until the callback is received?

Comment: You have many options.  Pass your callback as a parameter to ReceiveMessage, or have your calling class subscribe to an event where ReceiveMessage is located and in ReceiveCallback call the event delegate with the message, etc...

Comment: I repeat in a loop following instructions:
1. I send data asynchronously
2. I receive a message informing them of the possibility of sending data
3. If the received message == "Next" go to the next iteration of a loop

Receiving data not work properly because when I give a breakpoint in the method `ReceiveCallback()` and at the next instruction after `ReceiveMessage()` in the class which calls `ReceiveMessage()`...  instruction for ReceiveMessage () is performs sooner than ReceiveCallback ().

Answer (score 0):

You can give the class where `aMessage` is defined an event and let the class that calls `ReceiveMessage()` subscribe to it. So it will be informed when the data is ready.

Answer (score 0):

This is really where the async starts to shine. that way you can more eaily do it

```
public void ReceiveMessage()
{
    try {
       await socket.ReceiveAsync(messageBuffer,0,messageBuffer.Length,SocketFlags.None);
       aMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messageBuffer, 0, rec);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       Console.WriteLine("SEND ERROR\n{0}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Now the code after the await line will gets executed once your message has been received